# Fragment not visible in activity’s layout after fragment transaction.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, transactions, android-viewpager

I have a

```
public class MainFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements  ActionBar.TabListener
```

that contains several tabs in a FragmentPagerAdapter. In this app you can have 0, 1 or several pets. If you have 0 pets one of the tabs contain a fragment with nothing but an information text. If you have 1 pet the tab contains a fragment with information about it and the action bar is updated with a save button. If you have several pets the tab contains the same fragment as if you have 0 pets but the action bar contains a submenu where you can chose one of the pets. When you select one there is a fragment transaction that shall change to the same fragment as if you only had one pet. Also the fragment transaction shall update the action bar with a save button.

The two different fragmens work fine when I have 0 or 1 pet. The problem only occurs after the fragment transaction.

Here is what happens when I do the fragment transaction:

1. The current fragment is being destroyed and detached.
2. The new fragment is attached. onCreate(), onCreateView(), onResume, onCreateOptionsMenu() are run. The action bar menu is updated as it should but the tab is empty. When I run isInLayout() on the second fragment it returns false, however that happens when I run the method on my other (visible) fragments as well.

In onResume() in the second fragment the methods isVisible(), isMenuVisible(), isAdded() all return true. isHidden() returns false.

Since the code in the new/second fragment runs as it should I suppose the fragment transaction is ok? I have tried to run notifyDataSetChanged() on the FragmentPagerAdapter in MainFragmentActivity without result.

In MainFragmentActivity I use the following imports (and more but that’s not relevant for the question):

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
```

In the fragment I use the following imports:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.SubMenu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
```

As you can see I combine both v4 support with ActionBarSherlock. This has not (yet) been a problem.

This is what the transaction looks like:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.pager, secondFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

I have also tried

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pager, secondFragment).commit();
```

with the same result.

Here is the look of MainFragmentActivitys layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>        

</LinearLayout>
```

I have of course searched but not been able to find any other similar question here. Please help, how do I force the fragment to be added to Main’s layout?

Comment: I think the problem may lie in the fact that you try to replace the fragment directly. Instead, you should let the fragmentpageradapter create fragments based on the number of pets, thus when add/removing just change the model data and call notifydatasetchanged on the adapter. You might have to return NONE in get position method of the adapter to force the changes to happen when removing a pet.

Comment: On this tab the option to add/remove pets isn't there. Instead if you have several pets the same general information as if you don't have any pets should be shown. That is, until you choose one of your pets. I suppose a ViewPager "holds on" the its fragments in a different way than usual, because doing a fragment transaction doesn't seem to be this hard. I guess I will modify my fragments so that I only need one on that tab and instead change the contents depending on the number of pets and what the user chooses. Thank you for your prompt input.

Comment: Oh right, think I didn't read the question carefully enough. Is it also a problem if you instead of replacing the pager, call add in the transaction? I guess you could add the fragment without adding it to the back stack to make it seem as if you replace the pager.

Comment: Except from replace I tried different variations of the following;
transaction.hide(this);   
transaction.remove(this);
transaction.add(R.id.pager, secondFragment);
transaction.attach(secondFragment);

When I do the remove/hide thing the first fragment disappears, and the new one runs but without showing. Also tried FragmentTransaction transaction = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); instead of getActivity() that I usually use. 

I also tried to do a similar thing from MainFragmentActivity. Nothing seem to help.

Comment: You are doing the transaction from within another fragment? If so you should use getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: I have tried to replace the fragment both from the MainFragmentActivity and from the first fragment, with the same result. When I use getChildFragmentManager() the app crashes with the message "No view found..." so I guess that's only for nested fragments, instead of replacement in the same container.

Comment: I will have a look at some of my old code tomorrow. If I understand you correctly, I have made something similar previously. Not using sherlock though but can't see how that should cause problems

Comment: I would highly appreciate that. The alternative to use one single fragment and modify it is of course still there, even though I would hate to give up on something that really shouldn't be so hard. Because of the weird behaviour with the code running but not showing I still suspect the import/fragment combinations. But I really don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it has been quite some time ago that I did something similar (I think). Digging in to my code, it looks as if I have had troubles as well.

I found that I do not add the other fragments to the Viewpager layout, but to the parent `R.id.details` using this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Turios" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/display_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#333"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="#fff" >
        </android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the code that I have ended up using to handle tab selection.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    int position = tab.getPosition();
    FragmentTransaction t = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);

    if (position == DisplayFragment.NAVIGATION_INDEX) {

        if (!device.isMultiPane() && mapsFragment != null
                && mapsOptionsFragment != null) {
            t.detach(mapsFragment);
            t.detach(mapsOptionsFragment);
        }

        if (browserFragment != null) {
            t.detach(browserFragment);
        }

    }

    if (position == GoogleMapFragment.NAVIGATION_INDEX) {

        t = addMapFragment(t);

    }
    if (position == BrowserFragment.NAVIGATION_INDEX) {
        if (browserFragment == null) {
            browserFragment = new BrowserFragment();
            t.add(R.id.details, browserFragment,
                    Turios.FRAGMENT_BROWSER_TAG);
        } else {
            t.attach(browserFragment);
        }
    }

    t.commit();

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    int position = tab.getPosition();
    FragmentTransaction t = fm.beginTransaction();

    if (position == GoogleMapFragment.NAVIGATION_INDEX) {
        if (mapsFragment.isVisible() && mapsOptionsFragment.isVisible()) {
            t.detach(mapsFragment);
            t.detach(mapsOptionsFragment);
        }
    }
    if (position == BrowserFragment.NAVIGATION_INDEX) {
        if (browserFragment.isVisible()) {
            t.detach(browserFragment);
        }
    }
    t.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

private FragmentTransaction addMapFragment(FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (mapsFragment == null) {
        AddressHolder address = (device.isMultiPane()) ? null
                : getSelectedAddressHolder();
        mapsFragment = GoogleMapFragment.newInstance(address);
        ft.add(R.id.details, mapsFragment, Turios.FRAGMENT_MAP_TAG);

        mapsOptionsFragment = new GoogleMapOptionsFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.details, mapsOptionsFragment, FRAGMENT_MAP_OPTIONS_TAG);
    } else {
        ft.attach(mapsFragment);
        ft.attach(mapsOptionsFragment);
    }
    return ft;
}
```

So I keep a reference to my fragments as a public variable and manually attatch/detatch as needed. To handle orientation changes, restoring the fragments, I have in my `onCreate`:

```
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        Log.i(TAG, "savedInstanceState not null");

        // restore fragments
        browserFragment = (BrowserFragment) fm
                .findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_BROWSER_TAG);
        mapsFragment = (GoogleMapFragment) fm
                .findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_MAP_TAG);

        mapsOptionsFragment = (GoogleMapOptionsFragment) fm
                .findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_MAP_OPTIONS_TAG);
    }
    ...
```

I hope this helps you. If anything, it points towards the fact that it is not as simple as one would imagine.

Comment: As you wrote, it's not as simple as one would imagine. I suppose with this solution you don't use FragmentPagerAdapter at all, right? Due to the many fragments and activities in my app I think I shouldn't change the navigation structure too much and instead go for the versatile-fragment-workaround. Thank you very much for the patience and explanations. Since your solution works I'll accept it.

Comment: No problem :) actually I do use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter which is always 'added/visible' at the bottom to show some details, then if map or browser is selected, they are added on top of it (taking the selected page in the FragmentStatePagerAdapter into account, that is the map show the position of an address and such).

Comment: And adding a map or browser is simply a matter of 'attaching' it as shown in the code, if the fragment is available, otherwise it is added.